# Mobx changing state not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I'm using MobX for state management in my React Typescript app but changing the state isn't re-rendering the components

I made a code sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shtern-ifncks

any help is appreciated

Comment: I was able to find a solution, here is an updated code sandbox that works
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-stallman-keqsg5

Comment: Questions on stack overflow must be self-contained and thus the question itself should contain the necessary code, properly formatted. If you'd like you can include **an additional** link to something like a github page or a code sandbox.